# Singleton in constructor

Tags: php, constructor, singleton

why it's not work?
I want create singleton for connect to db, autoloader, router.

```
static $singleton = null;

public function __construct(){
    if(empty(self::$singleton)){
        self::$singleton = new self;
        return self::$singleton;
    }
    return self::$singleton;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "not work".

Comment: if you are about to create singleton with the context what it is meant for, you have to make the `constructor` protected and try a method say `getInstance` to instantiate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php method __construct always return instance of class, you can't manipulate the returned value.

To do what you meant to do, you should use private __conctruct() and create next method for example public static getInstance() with your code:

```
static $singleton = null;

public function getInstance(){
    if(empty(self::$singleton)){
        $class = get_called_class();
        self::$singleton = new $class;
    }
    return self::$singleton;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, really __construct return same class, i missed this :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way:

```
class Singleton {

    private static $singleton = null;

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}
    private function __sleep() {}
    private function __wakeup() {}

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(empty(self::$singleton)){
            self::$singleton = new self;
            return self::$singleton;
        }
        return self::$singleton;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the constructor, create a separate method:

```
public static function getInstance ()
{
    if (is_null(self::$singleton)) {
        self::$singleton = new self();
    }
    return self::$singleton;
}
```

The constructor is called when creating the object - in this case, the object should only be created once no matter how many times `getInstance()` is called.

Comment: Thank you! i missed this :)